# Project Euler 18/67: Maximum Sum from Top to Bottom of the Triangle

Tags: c++, c++11, programming-challenge

This is my attempt at Project 18/67 of Project Euler. You can see the problem information, and obtain the needed txt file from [here](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=67).

I had some help with the split function, and help on how to use an vector to do this. I would love any other feedback on this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

//function by jesyspa
std::vector<int> split(std::string line){
    std::stringstream ss (line);
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::string num;
    while(std::getline(ss, num, ','))
        result.push_back(std::stoi(num));
    return result;
}
int main(){

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid;

    //inputing triangle fule
    std::ifstream nums;
    nums.open("triangle.txt");
    std::string row;
    //Calling function, and pushing back into the vector
    while(std::getline(nums, row, '\n')){
        grid.push_back(split(row));
    }
    //term is one shorter then grid
    int term = grid.back().size() - 1;

    //This loop add's the larger of two bottom numbers, with the number above the first of the two.
    for(int a = term; a >= 1; a--){
        for(int b = 0; b <= a; b++){
            if(grid[a][b] > grid[a][b+1]){
                grid[a-1][b] += grid[a][b];
            }
            else{
                grid[a-1][b] += grid[a][b+1];
            }
        }
    }
    //Our answer
    std::cout << grid[0][0];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, I find that your code is clear. I just have a few remarks:

- You should order your headers in alhabetical order. It will help you to quickly check whether some header is already included or not in you plan to add some:

  ```
  #include <fstream>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <sstream>
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
  ```
- You should open your file directly from the constructor, and check whether there was a problem when you tried to open the file:

  ```
  std::ifstream nums.open("triangle.txt");
  if (not nums.good())
  {
      throw std::runtime_error("Could not open the file.");
  }
  ```
- You can replace this condition:

  ```
  if(grid[a][b] > grid[a][b+1]){
      grid[a-1][b] += grid[a][b];
  }
  else{
      grid[a-1][b] += grid[a][b+1];
  }
  ```

  You can use `std::max` instead:

  ```
  grid[a-1][b] += std::max(grid[a][b], grid[a][b+1]);
  ```
- I don't know why you chosed `,` as a separator since the original file uses a space as separator. Had you kept the space as a separator in your file, you vould have rewritten the function `split` with [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), with an `int` template parameter:

  ```
  std::vector<int> split(const std::string& line){
      std::stringstream ss(line);
      return {
          std::istream_iterator<int>{ss},
          std::istream_iterator<int>{}
      };
  }
  ```

  The braces after the `return` correspond to [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). The rules for list initialization are pretty complex; the curly braces after `return` mean that an instance of the anounced return type (`std::vector<int>`) should be created with the arguments between the braces. In our case, the chosen constructor is the one that matches the best two `istream_iterator<int>` instances:

  ```
  template<class InputIt>
  vector(InputIt first, InputIt last,
         const Allocator& alloc=Allocator());
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Not a really fancy comment but :

```
        if(grid[a][b] > grid[a][b+1]){
            grid[a-1][b] += grid[a][b];
        }
        else{
            grid[a-1][b] += grid[a][b+1];
        }
```

can easily be rewritten

```
        grid[a-1][b] += max(grid[a][b], grid[a][b+1])
```

Also, your function and algorithm deserve more documentation.

Answer (score 4):

One thing I see is that `split()`'s parameter should be passed by `const&` as it's not being modified within the function.  This is how objects should be passed if they're not to be modified, preventing an unnecessary copy of read-only data.

```
split(std::string const& line) {}
```