# Project Euler Problem 11: Largest product in a grid

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

Here is my implementation to project Euler Problem 11. I did this problem a bit later, when I learned how to input from a txt file. The problem context can be seen [here](http://projecteuler.net/problem=11). I did add "\n" to the end of each line, after copying the numbers into a txt file, I'm not sure of any other way to do that. Any other improvements anyone can think of?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


//splitting stream into ints.
std::vector<int> split(std::string line){
    std::stringstream ss (line);
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::string num;
    while(std::getline(ss, num, ' '))
        result.push_back(std::stoi(num));
    return result;
}
//comparing all int's that are horizontally next to each other
unsigned long long Horizontal(int a, int b, std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid){
    if(b < grid[a].size()-3){
        return (grid[a][b] * grid[a][b+1] * grid[a][b+2] * grid[a][b+3]);
    }
}
//comparing all int's that are vertically next to each other
unsigned long long Vertical(int a, int  b, std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid){
    if(a < grid.size()-3){
        return (grid[a][b] * grid[a+1][b] * grid[a+2][b] * grid[a+3][b]);
    }
}
//all int's that are diagonally(forward) next to each other
unsigned long long ForDiag(int a, int b, std::vector<std::vector<int>>grid){
    if (a < grid.size()-3 && b < grid[a].size()-3){
        return (grid[a][b] * grid[a+1][b+1] * grid[a+2][b+2] * grid[a+3][b+3]);
    }
}
//all int's that are diagonally(backward) next to each outher
unsigned long long BackDiag(int a, int b, std::vector<std::vector<int>>grid){
    b+=3; // b needs to be 3 larger for this function
    if(a < grid.size()-3 && b < grid[a].size()){
        return (grid[a][b] * grid[a+1][b-1] * grid[a+2][b-2] * grid[a+3][b-3]);
    }
}

//Calls the calculation functions, and compares them for the largest.
unsigned long long Largest(std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid ){
    int gwidth = grid[0].size();
    int glength = grid.size();
    unsigned long long largest = 0;

    for(int a = 0; a < gwidth; ++a){
        for(int b = 0; b < glength; ++b){
            largest = std::max(largest,Horizontal(a,b,grid));
            largest = std::max(largest,Vertical(a,b,grid));
            largest = std::max(largest,ForDiag(a,b,grid));
            largest = std::max(largest,BackDiag(a,b,grid));

        }
    }
    return largest;
}




int main(){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid;

    //opening file.
    std::ifstream nums;
    nums.open("grid.txt");
    std::string row;

    //Calling function, and pushing back into the vector
    while(std::getline(nums, row, '\n')){
        grid.push_back(split(row));
    }

    std::cout << Largest(grid);

}
```

Comment: [My answer to your previous question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47277/22222) about `const&` still applies to your `std::vector` parameters.

Comment: I suggest activating warning -Wreturn-type .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your functions returning a `unsigned long long` are missing a return which leads to undefined behavior ([more details on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pr/1610454#1610454)). You could throw an exception to handle this or you could just return `0`.

---

Not a real issue and mostly a matter of personal preference but the way you check that you are not going out of the bounds of the array could be written in a more natural way.

To check that index `b + 3` is in the array, I'd rather read `b + 3 < a.size()` than `b < a.size() - 3`.

---

Even more unusual is the pre-increment in the case of `BackDiag()` : you add `3` to `b` and then you consider `b - 3`.

---

Once your code re-written to take into account these comments, it looks like :

```
unsigned long long Horizontal(int a, int b, std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid){
    return (b + 3 < grid[a].size()) ?
        (grid[a][b] * grid[a][b+1] * grid[a][b+2] * grid[a][b+3]) :
        0;
}
//comparing all int's that are vertically next to each other
unsigned long long Vertical(int a, int  b, std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid){
    return (a + 3 < grid.size()) ?
        (grid[a][b] * grid[a+1][b] * grid[a+2][b] * grid[a+3][b]) :
        0;
}
unsigned long long ForDiag(int a, int b, std::vector<std::vector<int>>grid){
    return (a + 3 < grid.size() && b + 3 < grid[a].size()) ?
        (grid[a][b] * grid[a+1][b+1] * grid[a+2][b+2] * grid[a+3][b+3]) :
        0;
}
unsigned long long BackDiag(int a, int b, std::vector<std::vector<int>>grid){
    return (a + 3 < grid.size() && b + 3 < grid[a].size()) ?
        (grid[a][b+3] * grid[a+1][b+2] * grid[a+2][b+1] * grid[a+3][b]) :
        0;
}
```

---

Now, one thing to notice is that this good is basically always the same. You should try to write a generic function that you can reuse.

The signature would be something like :

```
unsigned long long computeProduct(int a, int b, int incrA, int incrB, std::vector<std::vector<int>>grid)
```

Answer (score 2):

One improvement you can make is to flatten the matrix to 1D and just use larger offsets.  This will speed your code up quite a bit.

```
//Create 1D vector
std::ifstream infile("grid.txt");   
std::vector<int> flatmatrix;
while(!infile.eof())
{
    double numtemp = 0;
    infile >> numtemp;
    flatmatrix.push_back(numtemp);
}

//Function to return the largest product as per problem description
//This is hardcoded for 20 X 20, but it shouldn't be too hard to adapt to take different sizes.
int MaxProduct(const std::vector<int>& matrix2)
{
    long temp = 0;
    long result2 = 0;
    size_t size = matrix2.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        temp = matrix2[i];
        //right
        if(i % 20 < 17)
        {
            temp = matrix2[i] * matrix2[i + 1] * matrix2[i + 2] * matrix2[i + 3];
            result2 = (temp > result2 ? temp : result2);
        }
        //down
        if((i + 60) < 400 && ((int)(i / 20)) % 20 < 17)
        {
            temp = matrix2[i] * matrix2[i + 20] * matrix2[i + 40] * matrix2[i + 60];
            result2 = (temp > result2 ? temp : result2);
        }
        //left
        if(i % 20 > 2)
        {
            temp = matrix2[i] * matrix2[i - 1] * matrix2[i - 2] * matrix2[i - 3];
            result2 = (temp > result2 ? temp : result2);
        }
        //up
        if((i - 60) >= 0 && ((int)(i / 20)) % 20 > 2)
        {
            temp = matrix2[i] * matrix2[i - 20] * matrix2[i - 40] * matrix2[i - 60];
            result2 = (temp > result2 ? temp : result2);
        }
        //down,right
        if(i % 20 < 17 && (i + 60) < 400 && ((int)(i / 20)) % 20 < 17)
        {
            temp = matrix2[i] * matrix2[(i + 20) + 1] * matrix2[(i + 40) + 2] * matrix2[(i + 60) + 3];
            result2 = (temp > result2 ? temp : result2);
        }
        //down,left
        if(i % 20 > 2 && (i + 60) < 400 && ((int)(i / 20)) % 20 < 17)
        {
            temp = matrix2[i] * matrix2[(i + 20) - 1] * matrix2[(i + 40) - 2] * matrix2[(i + 60) - 3];
            result2 = (temp > result2 ? temp : result2);
        }
        //up,right
        if(i % 20 < 17 && (i - 60) > -1 && ((int)(i / 20)) % 20 > 2)
        {
            temp = matrix2[i] * matrix2[(i - 20) + 1] * matrix2[(i - 40) + 2] * matrix2[(i - 60) + 3];
            result2 = (temp > result2 ? temp : result2);
        }
        //up,left
        if(i % 20 > 2 && (i - 60) > -1 && ((int)(i / 20)) % 20 > 2)
        {
            temp = matrix2[i] * matrix2[(i - 20) - 1] * matrix2[(i - 40) - 2] * matrix2[(i - 60) - 3];
            result2 = (temp > result2 ? temp : result2);
        }
    }
    return result2;
}
```

For future reference your `split` function can be simplified quite a bit:

```
std::vector<int> split(std::string line)
{
    std::stringstream ss (line);
    std::vector<int> result;
    int num;
    while(ss >> num)
        result.push_back(num);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I [already provided](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47274/15094) a simpler `split` in the previous question, but they simply didn't keep it for some reason :/